# Android Eclipse - CountDownTimer issue

Tags: android, eclipse

Currently I have basic countdown timer where it counts down 0.5 seconds and when its at 0 it changes to a different screen. However I want to do two things to this.

```
new CountDownTimer(500, 1000) {

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                textView2.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished);
             }

             public void onFinish() {
                 textView2.setText("done!");

                 Intent launchactivity= new Intent(Game.this,Mainmenu.class);                               
                 startActivity(launchactivity);
             }
          }.start();
```

This is currently activated when a button is pressed and I want the timer to reset everytime the button is pressed.
Also I would like to display the time left constantly, the currently method updates only every second.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cancelling and restarting CountDownTimer issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454527/cancelling-and-restarting-countdowntimer-issue)

Comment: Couldn't find that before, but I'm still not sure how to constantly update the time left

Comment: O sorry I didn't read that. Easy, just use a smaller value in the 2nd parameter, so the `onTick()` callback is called more often.

Comment: Im lost, I've been on this for too long, do you mean the (long millisUntilFinished) part?

Comment: Oh the 1000? So for example change it to 1?

Comment: Ok I've done it now, thanks for your help